# How to get "" instead of {} in TexStudio-bibliography?

Tags: texstudio

Quotation marks and braces may both function as delimiters in key fields in bib-files. In [WikiBook-LaTeX/Bibliography Management](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#BibTeX) it is reasonably suggested that one uses quotation marks (" and ") instead of braces ({ and }). My TeXstudio latex editor uses { and } by default when inserting bibliography entries.

Is there a setting in TeXstudio to change the defaults to quotation marks for the insertions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "" and {} in BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109064/is-there-a-difference-between-and-in-bibtex)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179225/numbers-in-bibtex-entries-syntax-highlighting-vs-reality that explains that numeric fields do not need any delimiter (just `year = 2021`).

Comment: @Marijn No, my question is not answered by what you link to. I know that quotation marks and braces are interchangeable in bib-files, and ask whether one may change the defaults of TexStudio to quotation marks for the inserted key fields.

Comment: Ah ok, I did not understand your question then. I have retracted my close vote. I guess the wording is a bit ambiguous, I interpreted "may one" as "is it allowed" and not "how to". I'll try to edit.

Comment: I find it unreasonable to use double quotes as delimiters: the braces help in balancing text.

Comment: @egreg Whether the text in a bibliography entry is balanced or not is a rather subjective matter, it seems to me. The author of the text I linked to emphasizes the potential for confusion between  the braces as delimiters and their special roles e.g. in preserving capital letters, and this appears to be a valid point.

Comment: @Sapiens I disagree. It's inconsistent with the standard conventions of TeX, for instance, and I fail to see a point in that consideration. Opinions, anyway.

Comment: @egreg I see your point with balancing the text now, and agree. If you write an answer, you will do a service if it moves someone to edit the Wikilatex book.